# Detect metadata about PDF from Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-chrome-extension

If my JavaScript code is running in a Chrome extension, and the browser has loaded a PDF file, can I detect metadata about the loaded PDF (number of pages, etc.)?  Extra challenge: the PDF itself is being loaded by a third-party browser extension.  I am looking for a way to do this that doesn't require inclusion of a huge library like pdf.js.

Comment: The built-in Chrome viewer can be poked for some things but certainly not an external extension because extensions can't access other extensions (except for a devtools custom panel while devtools is shown on an extension page).

Answer (score 0):

After some quick Google-fu I learned that PDFs store metadata in [XMP Format](https://www.pdflib.com/pdf-knowledge-base/xmp/xmp-overview/) (XML). So you can read the raw file data a pick out metadata with some simple regex.

Select a PDF file from your computer to see the demo:

```js
document.getElementById('f').oninput = async function() {
  var pdf = this.files[0];
  var details = await pdfDetails(pdf);
  console.log(details);
};

function pdfDetails(pdfBlob) {
  return new Promise(done => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      var raw = reader.result;
      var Pages = raw.match(/\/Type[\s]*\/Page[^s]/g).length;
      var regex = /<xmp.*?:(.*?)>(.*?)</g;
      var meta = [{
        Pages
      }];
      var matches = regex.exec(raw);
      while (matches != null) {
        matches.shift();
        meta.push({
          [matches.shift()]: matches.shift()
        });
        matches = regex.exec(raw);
      }
      done(meta);
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(pdfBlob);
  });
}
```

```html
<input type=file id=f accept=".pdf">
```

Answer (score -1):

A PDF document doesn't list the number of pages in its metadata.  Even if you added some custom metadata to track that information it wouldn't be in a standard way PDF readers would be expected to understand.

Comment: i guess you didn't bother to try my answer, which was posted several days before your incorrect answer.

Comment: In fact, after a few uploaded documents, the number of pages is the _only_ thing that is in the metadata lol.