# Get PDF Custom Metadata in Node.js / Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf, angular-universal

I am trying to get Custom Metadata from a PDF file in node (angular-universal).

The custom metadata is visible when logging the file as string, so i thought this would be an easy task.

## Packages i've tried

I tried the following packages and many more, but they all resulted in some errors or did not include custom metadata

#### pdfjs-dist

- works in client but stops working when running Server-side-rendering (angular-universal) because of DOM-dependencies
- problems with browser dependencies like canvas and more
- installing dependencies like canvas causes errors `canvas.node needs appropriate loader`. to this i only found solutions adjusting webpack config, but i dont have a custom-webpack builder with angular-universal (Server-side-rendering)

#### pdf-parse

- has not been updated for 3 years and always goes into debug mode because it has an outdated `let isDebugMode = !module.parent;` in index.js ([ISSUE](https://gitlab.com/autokent/pdf-parse/-/issues/15))
- when using a patch branch (`"pdf-parse": "gitlab:aduh95/pdf-parse#patch-1",`) there are other errors xx is not a function.

#### pdf-lib

- Works but does not support Custom metadata

## [Example file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SZMgVEo9ku-WgzeCUVEK5IOBEH-4N4No/view?usp=sharing)

### copied code snipet to test from [This Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56872725/detect-metadata-about-pdf-from-javascript)

- works for prepared metadata, but i got stuck trying to get the Custom metadata

```js
document.getElementById('f').oninput = async function() {
  var pdf = this.files[0];
  var details = await pdfDetails(pdf);
  console.log(details);
};

function pdfDetails(pdfBlob) {
  return new Promise(done => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      var raw = reader.result;
      var Pages = raw.match(/\/Type[\s]*\/Page[^s]/g).length;
      var regex = /<xmp.*?:(.*?)>(.*?)</g;
      var meta = [{
        Pages
      }];
      var matches = regex.exec(raw);
      while (matches != null) {
        matches.shift();
        meta.push({
          [matches.shift()]: matches.shift()
        });
        matches = regex.exec(raw);
      }
      done(meta);
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(pdfBlob);
  });
}
```

```html
<input type=file id=f accept=".pdf">
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "Custom Metadata"? What exact data in the example PDF file are you trying to get?

Comment: @Ryan there is metadata like "Page" or "Author" which is default. one of those is "Custom" where i can add any metadata. Apparently this Metadata is stored in XMP format. In my example document there is a custom metadata field called "jsonData" where i inserted stringified json data.